# Closure, where is the value getting stored?

Tags: javascript, closures

Over here, I am returning a function which is closed over the 'i' variable, creating a closure.

```
var myFunc = function(){
    var i = 0;
    function increment(){
        return ++i;
        console.log(i);
    }
    return increment
}
```

now If I assign this function to other variables like

```
var newFunc = myFunc();
var newFunc2 = myFunc();
```

calling any of them will result in

```
newFunc() // 1
newFunc() // 2
newFunc() // 3
newFunc2() // 1 ??
```

Where is the value of var i getting stored?
is it getting stored in the execution context of each function so that it can be changed only when we call that specific function.

Comment: *"Where is the value of var i getting stored?"* In the environment that is created every time you call `myFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you define the variable i inside the

```
myFunc
```

which means that the scope of the variable i will be within that function. So whenever you call this function, it will create create its own i.

Comment: `the scope of the variable i will be within that function` not just inside that function, inside that specific function call. Multiple calls to that function will create multiple variables `i` that are independant of each other, each one in its own, seperate scope.

Comment: `function call` Exactly! Thanks for commenting and appreciate your explanation.